How do I get Steam points?
Steam has a system where you can get points and use them to buy non-refundable cosmetics to spruce up your profile.
How do you get these points though?

According to Steam:

100 points for every $1.00 you spend. Buy any game, DLC, hardware, application, soundtrack, or in-game item, and get points.

Whenever you make a purchase on Steam, you'll be given Steam Points based on how much you spend. First, the amount is converted to USD, which then converts directly to the number of points you receive.
You will not receive any points for funding your Steam Wallet or for any Steam Community Market purchases.
You can also get Steam Points if someone from the community grants an award to one of your user reviews or other uploaded content such as screenshots, videos, guides, or Workshop items.
